# 2-category vs bicategory. 3-category vs tricategory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, higher-category-theory

1. What are the differences between "(strict or not) 2-category" or a "bicategory?"
2. What are the differences between "(strict or not) 3-category" or a "tricategory?"

It seems that the 2-category contains bicategory, 3-category contains tricategory, but not the other way around. How to sharpen the statements?

Comment: Bicategories are exactly weak 2-categories and so subsume (strict) 2-categories. Both have objects, morphisms, and 2-cells, but a weak 2-category simply has composition up to isomorphism, i.e. $(f \circ g) \circ h \simeq f \circ (g \circ h)$ (as well as for the identities, whereas a strict 2-category has composition up to equality, i.e. $(f \circ g) \circ h = f \circ (g \circ h)$ (as well as for the identities). Every strict 2-category is thus a weak 2-category, but not vice versa.

Comment: @varkor: you use a very interesting shorthand when you say '*a weak 2-category simply has composition up to isomorphism*', which in practice, is mostly the case, however, in the commonly agreed definitions, it is required that $f\circ g$ is uniquely specified for composable morphisms $f$ and $g$, and not only up to isomorphism (which would be even closer to reality). The formula you write after it, is about the *associativity* of the composition, which is only required to hold up to (coherent) isomorphisms.

Comment: @Berci: you are right, of course: I really meant "composition satisfying the usual laws up to isomorphism" (and $\cong$ rather than $\simeq$), but didn't pay close enough attention. Fortunately, the intended meaning is still clear!

Comment: Yes, it was indeed clear, and what I wanted to emphasize is that in the living examples, like tensor module of bimodules, your words are also literally true, in that the composition itself is given only up to isomorphism in these cases by nature.